# giving id to many objects - is it a bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was working on a django project and soon the template became a mess and ended up with nearly all elements having an ID (just to clarify, **all IDs are unique**). I can reduce the number of IDs by giving their parents  an ID but that would increase my jQuery code. So what I am asking is

> Is it better to have many IDs in HTML **or** slightly less IDs and a bit longer JS/jQuery code?

Here's a sample code:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>
            <a href="/vote/" class="vote" id="story-vote-26"><img src="/static/images/arrow.gif"></a>
            <a href="http://www.lettersofnote.com/2012/10/people-simply-empty-out.html" class="title" id="story-title-26">“People simply empty out”</a> <span class="domain">(www.lettersofnote.com)</span>
        </p>
        <p class="story-info">
            <span id="story-points-26">660</span> points by tantaman &#448; 31 minutess ago
        </p>
    </li>
    ...
```

there are at least 100 of these `li` and each with 4 IDs (I haven't added 4th one yet). So total of 400 IDs, or 100 IDs if I add ID to `li`s instead

Comment: It's hard to be definitive with this fuzzy question but there is no problem in having many id, the look-up algorithm won't suffer.

Comment: if you can manage having ids will improve the performace

Comment: simple: yes. The ID is for a single object to identify it. sue classes for multiply objects!

Comment: This is a vague question, but the short answer is: ID's are fine, but are they the most efficient way to access the element? Do you need this many ID's, or can you access by class, DOM-walking, element names, etc? Seeing some sample html & js would be helpful.

Comment: @dystroy Great, thanks! But what would be better? I'll have to use a selector like `#parent > p > a` instead of `#anchor` and than can reduce IDs by a factor of 3. Also, jQuery uses that selector only on click so it doesn't fire up straight away as soon as page loads

Comment: Use an id when it makes your code simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in having many id. Hash algorithms used to look for elements scale very well.

So, as long as you don't have performance problems that you could solve using id, the main rules to choose if you should add some id should be :

- does it make the code more readable (a more concise code is often more readable) ?
- does it make the code easier to evolve ?

Don't make your code more complex just to add some id but there's no hidden cost in having them.

Comment: I guess ID on `li` does make my code more readable and easier to evolve. SO ID on `li` it is !! Thanks for the help and patience **dystroy** `+1`

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of IDs is to identify an element uniquely in DOM. **It is mostly useful to pinpoint elements for using in JavaScript and CSS.**

As long as, your application of these IDs are based on this rule, **Its GOOD**.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** it is better to have elements with unique id.It helps javascript ans CSS to select and manipulate dom. But no two elements should have same id.
`Increasing javascript code will increase page load time.` **so its better to reduce javascript code and have unique id for html elements if required**

Comment: Increasing the amount of markup (such as adding ID's) also increases load times...

Comment: add id where ever it servers your purpose

Comment: After reading Dystroy's answer, I decided to give ID to parent. Plus, it just caused a few extra bytes in my JS, I'll get them back after I minigy my JS `:P`